# Hello I want, I make a program that stores names and stop when writing"stop" ends and the program displays the names stored in this

Tags: java, arrays

I make a program that stores names and stop when writing"stop" ends and the program displays the names stored in this ......This code displays the last name you've entered i want to display all names

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);       
     System.out.println("Enter The name : ");
     String name = sc.next(); 

     while (!"stop".equals(name)){
         System.out.println("please entrr new name :  ");
         name = sc.next();


}
     System.out.println(name);

}
  }
```

Comment: You haven't stated where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with storing data is that you actually have to store the data somewhere ;). You can use an `Array` of `String`s or pretty much any kind of `Collection`. In this case I'd say simple `ArrayList` is the best. So you create the list:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you append elements to the list by using `add()` method. For example:

```
names.add(name);
```

You can easily print an output with build in `toString()` method like this:

```
System.out.println(names);
```

or iterate through the list and print them yourself. Note that you probably don't want to store the "stop" String in your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(); // declaring dynamic array
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter The name : ");
        String name = sc.next();
        int i = 0;

        while (!"stop".equals(name)) {

            System.out.println("please entrr new name :  ");

            name = sc.next();
            a.add(name); // each time you add your name to the array and store 
            i++;

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++)
            System.out.println(a.get(j));

    }
```

Check this it should work because in your code you do not store the names anywhere and each time you just overwrite it but with ArrayList you store your names and then you can use it anywhere.

Comment: a.add(name); add this line after the String name = sc.next();